# How to programmatically download and install SQL Server Express (32 or 64 depending on OS)

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, deployment

How to programmatically download from internet and install SQL Server Express (32 or 64 depending on OS) using C#?

The scenario is I am deploying a desktop application for Point of Sales. Before installing, I want to make sure that SQL Server is installed on the client machine, and if not, I want to download it from the internet and install it.

Comment: If you are installing your software, just use MSI dependencies. You can achieve this in Wix, InstallShield or Advanced installer. What installation flavour are you using?

Comment: visual studio deployment

Comment: i can't find any product in Google called `visual studio deployment `. Can you provide some doco or a link?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/2kt85ked(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: That document you linked has a section explaining how to do what you want: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio Installer Deployment refers to installation packages that must be installed before your project as **prerequisites**. According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7eh4aaa5(v=vs.100).aspx), to add a prerequisite:

> 1. In Solution Explorer, select the deployment project.
> 2. On the Project menu, click Properties.
> 3. In the Property Pages dialog box, expand the Configuration Properties node, and then select the Build property page.
> 4. Click the Prerequisites button.
> 5. In the Prerequisites dialog box, make sure that the Create setup program to install prerequisite components box is checked.
> 6. In the Choose which prerequisites to install list, select the prerequisites that you want to install, and then click OK.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public partial class Class1
    {

        private static WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        private static ManualResetEvent handle = new ManualResetEvent(true);
        private static string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
        private static Thread thread;
        private BackgroundWorker worker = null;


        void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            // "SQL Server Download Completed...";
            //install SQL Server
            string pathUser = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            Process.Start(pathUser, @"/q /Action=Install /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS /Hideconsole /Features=SQLEngine /InstanceName=SQLSERVER2012  /SECURITYMODE= “SQL” /UPDATEENABLED=false /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /SQLSVCACCOUNT=""NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM"" /BROWSERSVCSTARTUPTYPE=""Automatic""");

        }

        private void DownloadSQL()
        {
            string output = string.Empty;
            pathUser = pathUser.Replace("\\", "/");
            string filePath = "http://www.almsysinc.com/soft/files/microsoft/SQLEXPR_x86_ENU_2012.exe";
            var files = filePath.Split('/');
            pathUser = pathUser + @"/" + files[files.Count() - 1];
            thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(filePath), pathUser);
                handle.WaitOne(); // wait for the async event to complete
            });
            thread.Start();
        }
```